# Replace a line with a pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace a line when a pattern (only one pattern I have in that file) found with the below code, but it replaced whole content of the file.
Could you please advise or any better way with pathlib ?

```
import datetime

def insert_timestamp():
    """ To Update the current date in DNS files """
    pattern = '; serial number'
    current_day = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    subst = "\t" + str(current_day) + "01" + " ; " + pattern

    print(current_day)

   
    with open(lab_net_file, "w+") as file:
        for line in file:
            file.write(line if pattern not in line else line.replace(pattern, subst))

lab_net_file = '/Users/kams/nameserver/10_15'
insert_timestamp()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the output I wanted with this block of code.

```
    def insert_timestamp(self):
        """ To Update the current date in DNS files """
        pattern = re.compile(r'\s[0-9]*\s;\sserial number')
        current_day = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
        subst = "\t" + str(current_day) + "01" + " ; " + 'serial number'


        with open(lab_net_file, "r") as file:
            reading_file = file.read()
            pattern = pattern.search(reading_file).group()

        reading_file = reading_file.replace(pattern, subst)

        with open(lab_net_file, "w") as file:
            file.write(reading_file)
```

Thank you @Timmy

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is read the file, replace the pattern, and write to it again like this:

```
with open(lab_net_file, "r") as file:
    read = file.read()

read = read.replace(pattern, subst)


with open(lab_net_file, "w") as file:
    file.write(read)
```

The reason that you don't need to use if/else is because if there is no pattern inside `read`, then `.replace` won't do anything, and you don't need to worry about it. If `pattern` is inside `read`, then `.replace` will replace it throughout the entire string.

Comment: Thank! my bad, my requirement is to replace the whole line with subst if the pattern found, not to replace the pattern with subst.